# Problem while using Vulas for scanning gradle projects

Tags: gradle, vulas

I am trying scan my projects in gradle using [Vulas](https://github.com/SAP/vulnerability-assessment-tool) and always get the same error:

"Application context is required to execute goal APP."

Could you tell me what is missing or what exactly this error means? What exactly Vulas is trying to looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this error is that Vulas does not know the application's unique identifier.

How to specify this identifier depends on the programming language and build tool:

- Maven (Java): The identifier is automatically taken from `pom.xml`.
- Gradle (Java): The identifier is partly taken from `build.gradle` and has to be complemented with information from `gradle.properties` (properties `group` and `version`).
- Setuptools (Python): The identifier is automatically taken from `setup.py`.
- CLI: The identifier has to be specified using configuration parameters `vulas.core.appContext.group`, `vulas.core.appContext.artifact` and `vulas.core.appContext.version`.

Cheers, Henrik

Comment: Unfortunately, i have properties: `group` and `version` inside `gradle.properties` file and still get above error. However, i noticed that you guys just released a fresh new version of Vulas ver. 3.0.9 with refactored gradle plugin. After switching to that version the error gone and my scan works well :)

Comment: True, version 3.0.9 resolved some issues with the Vulas plugin for Gradle